# Terminology: Non-tree graph?

Tags: data-structures, graph, terminology

I'm new to data structures, and had a question on terminology. Is there a term for non-tree like graphs?

I realize that bidirectional/undirected graphs are inherently non-tree like. Is that the appropriate term? I'm asking because it seems that the tree is such a common subcategory of a graph that I figured there might be a term denoting all graphs that fall outside the subcategory.

P.s.: Please feel free to hack through any vernacular above. Would love tips on appropriate terminology in general concerning data structures.

Comment: Directionality of edges is independent of whether a graph is a tree.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a single universal term for a non-tree graph (except perhaps "non-tree graph" itself).

[Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) are connected, acyclic, directed graphs, with some additional rules like each node (except the root) having exactly one parent. Some kinds of trees have other additional rules that are not common among other kinds of graphs (such as there being a significance to the order of a node's children). Depending on which of those limitations a non-tree graph violates, you might describe it differently.

A tree-like graph that is not fully connected can be described as a "forest". A forest has several root nodes, each anchoring a disjoint subtree.

If you have a graph with multiple root nodes, but their descendents overlap (so that a given child node may have more than one parent node), you have a "[multitree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitree)". A human family tree may be a multitree if there there are no marriages between cousins or other relatives.

The next more general term is probably a "[directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)" or "DAG". A DAG is more general than a multitree because an ancestor node may be connected to a descendent node by more than one path. Human genealogical trees are more properly though of as DAGs, since sufficiently distant relatives are generally allowed to get married and have children (but nobody can be their own ancestor). There are many algorithms designed to work on DAGs, as forbidding cycles allows better performance for many useful applications (such as path finding).

More general still is a "[directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph)" or "digraph", which relaxes the restrictions cycles. A common digraph data structure is an adjacency list (a list of arcs from one node to another).

I don't think there's any more general term beyond that, other than just "graph". If you have a specific application for a graph, there might be a specialized term for the kind of graph you will use (and perhaps algorithms or even library code to go along with it), but you'd need to ask about that specifically.

Comment: Awesome! That really helps clear things up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @ReidasaurusRex: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Not exactly: a tree is an *undirected* graph that is connected and acyclic, see this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)). If you want to refer to a *directed* tree (also called *polytree*) you cannot use your definition, because "acyclic" only prohibits *directed cycles* but not semicycles. So you should say "no cycles" or equivalently "no undirected cycles" (= no directed cycles and no semicycles) instead of "acyclic". See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225762/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-tree-for-directed-graphs) for more details.